# How to get position of delimited separated string in C

Tags: c

How do i get the position of delimited separated string?

My text file looks like

```
at:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash

avahi:x:109:111:User for Avahi:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false

beagleindex:x:110:112:User for Beagle indexing:/var/cache/beagle:/bin/bash
```

My C code looks like

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *str, *saveptr;
char ch[100];
char *sp;
FILE *f;
int j;
char searchString[20];
char *pos;
f = fopen("passwd", "r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while opening the file");
}
while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, f)!= NULL)
{
    /*printf("%s\n", ch); */

    for (j = 1, str = ch; ; j++, str= NULL)
    {
         char *token = strtok_r(str, ": ", &saveptr);
         if (token == NULL)
             break;
         //printf("%s---\n---", token);
         printf("%s",token);

     }    


 }  


fclose(f);
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: i have nothing wrong. I want to get the position now so that i can search string through that position and display the record. I dont know how to proceed further or do the code

Comment: OKay.New Question now: Suppose i Want to match a string in the tokens. What should i write? PS the string which i need to be searched is given through command line argument

Comment: Regarding your original question - I think there is a better option than using the `strtok()` function for getting _position_ of tokens. Since you are looking for the _position_ of tokens, just walk through each line and do a comparison, char by char, keeping an index array for positions on each line. See code example in answer below...

Comment: Regarding New Question:_Suppose i Want to match a string in the tokens._  If you want to match a string from the command line, to the input content (whether from file or stdin) consider framing up and posting a new question.  Other than that, @Chris 's suggestion works

Answer (score 1):

well, using `strtok(str, ": ",` will split your string on spaces as well as colons, which is probably not what you want.  In addition, `strtok` treats multiple consecutive delimiter characters as a single delimiter (so it will never return an empty string between two colons), which is not what you want for parsing passwd.

Instead, you probably just want to use strchr:

```
while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, f)!= NULL) {
    char *token, *end;
    for (j = 1, token = ch; token; j++, token = end) {
        if ((end = strchr(token, ':'))) *end++ = 0;
        ...do something with token and j
```

Comment: OKay.New Question now: Suppose i Want to match a string in the tokens. What should i write? P.S the string which i need to be searched is given through command line argument

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you have to use `strtok()` just to get the *position* of a token separated by delimiters, rather simply walk through each line, and do a char by char comparison for the delimiter...  (hope this will help you)

I prepared an input file called GetDelimPosition.txt:

```
at:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash
avahi:x:109:111:User for Avahi:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
jamil:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash
javier:x:109:111:User for Avahi:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
jiame:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash
jose:x:109:111:User for Avahi:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
```

And used the following code: (of course you will modify as needed)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
//edit this line as needed:
#define FILE_LOC "C:\\dev\\play\\GetDelimPosition.txt"
int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char ch[260];
    int line=-1;
    int position[80][100]={0}; //lines x DelimPosition
    memset(position, 0, 80*100*sizeof(int));
    int i=-1,j=0, k=0;
    int len;

    fp = fopen(FILE_LOC, "r");

    while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, fp)!= NULL)
    {
        line++; //increment line
        len = strlen(ch);
        for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            if(ch[j] == ':') 
            {
                position[line][k] = j+1;//position of token (1 after delim)
                k++; //increment position index for next token
            }
        }
        k=0; //getting new line, zero position index
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

***To get the following results:*** (rows are lines in file, columns are positions of each token.  First token is assumed at position 0, and not reported)

[image]

Comment: Re-posted from ***[question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19354511/645128)*** after discovering it is a duplicate of this one.  Will delete the other answer.