# How do i get the position of tokens seperated by delimeter in C

Tags: c, strtok

My text file look like:

at:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash

avahi:x:109:111:User for Avahi:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false

Now i want to get the position of tokens seperated by delimeters. like eg at-position 1, x--position 2, 25--position 3 and so on.

Now my for loop is not working for(int i=0; i

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *str, *saveptr;
char ch[100];
char *sp;
FILE *f;
int j;
char searchString[20];
char *src;
f = fopen("passwd", "r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while opening the file");
    //exit(1);
}
char *dup;
while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, f)!= NULL)
{
    /*printf("%s\n", ch); */
      dup = strdup(ch);

    for (j = 1, str = ch; ; j++, str= NULL)
    {
         for(int i = 0;i < str;i++)
         {
             char *token = strtok_r(str, ":", &saveptr);
             if (token == NULL)
             break;

             src[i] = token;
             printf("%s", src[i]);
         }
         //printf("%s---\n---", token);
         //printf("%s",token);


if (strstr(token, argv[2]) != NULL)
         {

                printf(dup);
         }

    }





 }


fclose(f);
```

}

Comment: I think you may be letting your objective _get the position of tokens seperated by delimeters_ mis-guide you into using the `strtok()` function. Although it sounds appropriate, you are looking for the _position_ of tokens.  Just walk through each line and do a comparison, `char` by `char`, keeping an index array for positions on each line.  See code example in answer below...

Comment: Just wanted to note -- if you really want to read an `/etc/passwd` file you can use `getpwent` (`man 3 getpwent`) to iterate over each entry instead of rolling your own code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i < str;i++)
```

You are doing it wrong. You are comparing `i with an address` which is larger than i=0 so this loop won't start. I see you are breaking the loop when `NULL` is reached, so this should be you for loop

```
for(int i = 0; ;i++)
```

Comment: will i get the position of tokens ? if yes how ? i mean what shuld i write in code ?